# How to purge Robo 3T on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, robo3t

I want to purge Robomongo (Robo 3T) on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
sudo apt-get purge robo3t
[sudo] password for apricot: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package robo3t
```

Answer (score 2):

If I did not misunderstand you want to uninstall robo3t which was installed from the [`tar.gz`](https://robomongo.org/download) obtained from the official website. In addition, `apt` can only uninstall packages that where installed by apt.

Simply delete the robo3t folder to get rid of Robo 3T.

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406
```